# Ag-grid Angular, focus inside CellRenderComponent's elements

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am using ag-grid 11 with Angular 4.4.7 and typescript 2.3. When I have focus on an input box in a grid cell and using tab key to move focus to next grid cell as expected in a table in html, cursor moves to address bar instead of moving to next input box.

If someone has come across the same problem and have solution, please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like it could be an issue with the [tabIndex](https://dev.to/neshaz/html-tabindex-explained-2k9m). If you are using the [tabToNextCell](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-keyboard-navigation/#tabtonextcell) config for your grid, please add some implementation code and I will update this answer. Do the cells have this set and in the order you would like? If you are unsure, you can inspect/edit the html in the browser, check or add the tabIndex, and test by tabbing.

If you've already solved this problem, awesome! (and please let us know)!